# Run Method OnCallback In Dedicated Thread

Tags: android, multithreading

TLDR; **Run a method that updates the UI on a dedicated thread from a OnCallBack function that is updated every few milliseconds!!**

I'm getting a live stream video using Vitamio library and displaying it on a `SurfaceView` This is done by the `MediaPlayer` of the library.

However, I need to split the screen for VR experience. If `MediaPlayer` had a method to display the video on 2 `SurfaceView`s then I would not have had such a problem. Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Therefore, I figured that the live stream video runs on the `SurfaceView` in first half of the screen and I display each frame image `Bitmap` to an `ImageView` which occupies the second half of the screen.

This is working but not good... The problem is that copying the image is too much work and that's why the `ImageView` is laggy.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceview_livestream"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_livestream"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/live_stream" />
</LinearLayout>


public class LiveStreamManager implements MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdate {
   // some irrelevant code
   public void initLiveStream() {
      io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer();
      mediaPlayer.setDisplay(mainActivity.getSurfaceView());
      // other irrelevant code...
   }

   @Override
   public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
       Bitmap frame = mp.getCurrentFrame();
       if (frame != null) { 
          mainActivity.setFrame(frame);
       }
    }
} 


public MainActivity extends Activity {
     // some code...

     // I want this to run on a dedicated thread
     public void setFrame(Bitmap frame) {
         imageviewLiveStream.setImageBitmap(frame);
     }
}
```

Comment: @GhostCat how to create the Thread and give it a method that when it is called it gets executed on that thread

Comment: did you even read the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using rxJava:

```
Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.handlerThread())
                .map(t -> {
                    // do rendering here (on single render thread
                    return 'rendered images'
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe( t -> {
                    // set bitmaps here
                });
```

Rendering will be one on separate thread (create scheduler in advance ) every 10 milliseconds, then results will be processed on main thread.

Comment: what's the AndroidSchedulers ?

Comment: Hint: google helps ... https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/The-RxJava-Android-Module